# Are Java and C# regular expressions compatible?

Tags: c#, java, .net, regex

Both languages claim to use Perl style regular expressions. If I have one language test a regular expression for validity, will it work in the other? Where do the regular expression syntaxes differ?

The use case here is a C# (.NET) UI talking to an eventual Java back end implementation that will use the regex to match data.

Note that I only need to worry about matching, not about extracting portions of the matched data.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

There are quite (a lot of) differences.

#### Character Class

1. Character classes subtraction `[abc-[cde]]`

   - .NET **YES (2.0)**
   - Java: Emulated via character class intersection and negation: `[abc&&[^cde]]`)
2. Character classes intersection `[abc&&[cde]]`

   - .NET: Emulated via character class subtraction and negation: `[abc-[^cde]]`)
   - Java **YES**
3. `\p{Alpha}` POSIX character class

   - .NET **NO**
   - Java **YES (US-ASCII)**
4. Under `(?x)` mode <sup>[`COMMENTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS)/[`IgnorePatternWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)</sup>, space (U+0020) in character class is *significant*.

   - .NET **YES**
   - Java **NO**
5. [Unicode Category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) (L, M, N, P, S, Z, C)

   - .NET **YES**: `\p{L}` form only
   - Java **YES**:

     - From Java 5: `\pL`, `\p{L}`, `\p{IsL}`
     - From Java 7: `\p{general_category=L}`, `\p{gc=L}`
6. [Unicode Category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) (Lu, Ll, Lt, ...)

   - .NET **YES**: `\p{Lu}` form only
   - Java **YES**:

     - From Java 5: `\p{Lu}`, `\p{IsLu}`
     - From Java 7: `\p{general_category=Lu}`, `\p{gc=Lu}`
7. [Unicode Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block)

   - .NET **YES**: `\p{IsBasicLatin}` only. ([Supported Named Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks))
   - Java **YES**: (name of the block is free-casing)

     - From Java 5: `\p{InBasicLatin}`
     - From Java 7: `\p{block=BasicLatin}`, `\p{blk=BasicLatin}`
8. Spaces, and underscores allowed in all long block names (e.g. `BasicLatin` can be written as `Basic_Latin` or `Basic Latin`)

   - .NET **NO**
   - Java **YES** (Java 5)

#### Quantifier

1. `?+`, `*+`, `++` and `{m,n}+` (possessive quantifiers)

   - .NET **NO**
   - Java **YES**

#### Quotation

1. `\Q...\E` escapes a string of metacharacters

   - .NET **NO**
   - Java **YES**
2. `\Q...\E` escapes a string of character class metacharacters (in character sets)

   - .NET **NO**
   - Java **YES**

#### Matching construct

1. Conditional matching `(?(?=regex)then|else)`, `(?(regex)then|else)`, `(?(1)then|else)` or `(?(group)then|else)`

   - .NET **YES**
   - Java **NO**
2. Named capturing group and named backreference

   - .NET **YES**:

     - Capturing group: `(?<name>regex)` or `(?'name'regex)`
     - Backreference: `\k<name>` or `\k'name'`
   - Java **YES** ([Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(java.lang.String))):

     - Capturing group: `(?<name>regex)`
     - Backreference: `\k<name>`
3. Multiple capturing groups can have the same name

   - .NET **YES**
   - Java **NO** (Java 7)
4. Balancing group definition `(?<name1-name2>regex)` or `(?'name1-name2'subexpression)`

   - .NET **YES**
   - Java **NO**

#### Assertions

1. `(?<=text)` (positive lookbehind)

   - .NET **Variable-width**
   - Java **Obvious width**
2. `(?<!text)` (negative lookbehind)

   - .NET **Variable-width**
   - Java **Obvious width**

#### Mode Options/Flags

1. [`ExplicitCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option `(?n)`

   - .NET **YES**
   - Java **NO**

#### Miscellaneous

1. `(?#comment)` inline comments

   - .NET **YES**
   - Java **NO**

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info - Comparison of Different Regex Flavors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)
- [MSDN Library Reference - .NET Framework 4.5 - Regular Expression Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Pattern (Java Platform SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: that's going the extra mile. ;)

Comment: Typo (I assume) in #15: "(does not have NAMED capturing groups)"

Comment: # \pL through \pC or \p{IsL} through \p{IsC} (Unicode properties) -- You're wrong, .NET does have it, but it's called \p{L} instead of \pL or \p{IsL}.

Comment: Comments are allowed in regular expressions in Java when compiled with the `x` flag though the syntax differs from C#.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS

Comment: it should be "quantifiers allowed"(instead of Full regex),"quantifiers not allowed"(Finite length)

Comment: Named capture groups are allowed in Java since 1.7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(java.lang.String)

Comment: + 1 for being thourough

Answer (score 6):

Check out: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html
Plenty of regex info on that site, and there's a nice chart that details the differences between java & .net.

Comment: +1 good info. If anyone wants to pull out the high-level data from here (named groups, full string v. partial matches, etc) I'll mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

c# regex has its own convention for named groups `(?<name>)`. I don't know of any other differences.

Comment: are named groups used for matching? or for extracting the matched portions after the match?

Answer (score 2):

.NET Regex supports counting, so you can match nested parentheses which is something you normally cannot do with a regular expression. According to Mastering Regular Expressions that's one of the few implementations to do that, so that could be a difference.

Comment: I think you mean, so you can match NESTED parentheses (as well as other nested structures). No, Java's built-in regex flavor has no equivalent for that.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses standard Perl type regex as well as POSIX regex. Looking at the C# documentation on regexs, it looks like that Java has all of C# regex syntax, but not the other way around.

Compare them yourself: [Java](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):   [C#:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x.aspx)

**EDIT:**
[Currently, no other regex flavor supports Microsoft's version of named capture.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

Comment: No, .Net has several features Java lacks, as well as vice-versa. In fact, when it comes to cool features, I'd say .Net has a clear lead.  But I think they made a big mistake leaving out possessive quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience:

**Java 7 regular expressions as compared to .NET 2.0 regular expressions:**

- Underscore symbol in group names is not supported
- Groups with the same name (in the same regular expression) are not supported (although it may be really useful in expressions using "or"!)
- Groups having captured nothing have value of `null` and not of an *empty string*
- Group with index 0 also contains the whole match (same as in .NET) BUT is not included in `groupCount()`
- *Group back reference* in replace expressions is also denoted with dollar sign (e.g. $1), but if the same expression contains dollar sign as the end-of-line 
  marker - then the back reference dollar should be escaped (\$), otherwise in Java we get the "illegal group reference" error
- End-of-line symbol ($) behaves greedy. Consider, for example, the following expression (Java-string is given): "bla(bla(?:$|\r\n))+)?$". Here the last 
  line of text will be NOT captured! To capture it, we must substitute "$" with "\z".
- There is no "Explicit Capture" mode.
- Empty string doesn't satisfy the ^.{0}$ pattern.
- Symbol "-" must be escaped when used inside square brackets. That is, pattern "[a-z+-]+" doesn't match string "f+g-h" in Java, but it does in .NET. To match 
  in Java, pattern should look as (Java-string is given): "[a-z+\-]+".

NOTE: "(Java-string is given)" - just to explain double escapes in the expression.