# How to include named capture groups in java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regex in Java and I can't figure out how to include named capture groups in an expression. I'm writing a ScrewTurn Image Converter for [Confluence's Universal Wiki Converter](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/UWC/UWC+Developer+Documentation). This is what I have:

```
String image = "\\[image(?<align>auto)?\\|\\|{UP\\(((?<namespace>\\w+)\\.)?(?<pagename>[\\w-]+)\\)}(?<filename>[\\w- ]+\\.[\\w]+)\\]";

Pattern imagePattern = Pattern.compile(image, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

It's throwing this exception in `Pattern.comiple()`:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown look-behind group near index 19
\[image(?<align>auto)?\|\|{UP\(((?<namespace>\w+)\.)?(?<pagename>[\w-]+)\)}(?<filename>[\w- ]+\.[\w]+)\]
                   ^
```

I've used named capture groups like this before in C# `(?<namedgroup>asdf)`, but not in Java. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java doesn't support named captures.

Source: [Are Java and C# regular expressions compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538579/are-java-and-c-regular-expressions-compatible)

Comment: It does now in JDK 7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/415635/1449525

Answer (score 6):

It appears Java will only start supporting named capturing groups in version 7: [Matcher (SE 6)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) vs [Matcher (SE 7)](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Also see: http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname