# How to make regular expression match if a group of symbols is repeated only?

Tags: c#, java, regex

I need a regular expression that may match dates. However the delimiter of day, month and year may differ. It may be a dot, a dash, a slash...

What I have is

```
^([012]?[1-9]|3[01])[\\.\\-\\/\\\\](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\\.\\-\\/\\\\](19|20)\\d{2}$
```

So it's

```
([012]?[1-9]|3[01]) --the day part
(0?[1-9]|1[012])    --the month part
(19|20)\\d{2}       --the year part
```

The delimiter is repeated twice and, according to my current expression `[\\.\\-\\/\\\\]`, may be different...I mean, it matchs, say:

```
01.01-1986
```

While I want it to match only when there two dots, or two dashes, or two of whatever the delimiter part allows...So the example given above should NOT match.

I suppose it can somehow be done with grouping pattern of regular expressions. But I have no idea of how to apply this. Also I found myself to be absolutely not aware of how to google this...

Could anyone push me towards the right direction?

---

P.S.: I've recently watched [SO Regular Expression to match valid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates)...In my case I do understand that it'll match the 31st in months that do not have it, and all the days absent in February...it's all alright...

---

In Java I currently use the following code:

```
String value = "31/12/2086";
String pattern = ...
boolean result = value.matches(pattern);
```

In C#

```
string value = "01.01.2014";
string pattern = "";
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(value, pattern);
```

If there is a way to do what I want to, it would be great if the solution would be appliable to both these languages...[Are Java and C# regular expressions compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538579/are-java-and-c-sharp-regular-expressions-compatible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\\x` in your regular expression where `x` is group number. It represents same string that is matched by group `x`. So in your case you can use something like

```
someRegex([.\\-/\\\\])someOtherRegex\\1anotherRegex
          ^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^^
            group 1                 here should appear same string as in group 1
```

example

```
String regex = "someRegex([.\\-/\\\\])someOtherRegex\\1anotherRegex";
System.out.println("someRegex.someOtherRegex.anotherRegex".matches(regex));
System.out.println("someRegex.someOtherRegex-anotherRegex".matches(regex));
System.out.println("someRegex-someOtherRegex-anotherRegex".matches(regex));
```

output:

```
true
false
true
```

Comment: That's what I thought when you accepted my answer :) Anyway I am glad you like it :D