# Removing all punctuation using POSIX in Java and C# produce different output

Tags: java, c#, regex, punctuation

Here is my try:

Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String text = "This && is **^^ a ~~@@ test.";
 System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}").matcher(text).replaceAll(""));
 // OUT: This  is  a  test --> As I expected
}
```

C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
 string text = "This && is **^^ a ~~@@ test.";
 Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, "\\p{P}", ""));
 // OUT: This  is ^^ a ~~ test
 // expected: This  is  a  test
 Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Try this     [\p{P}\^]

Comment: See also: [Are Java and C# regular expressions compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538579/are-java-and-c-sharp-regular-expressions-compatible). (Spoiler alert: not necessarily...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\\p{P}"` means that same in both [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#unicode) and [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?view=netframework-4.7.2#character-classes), i.e. match Unicode Category `P` (Punctuation).

Java's `"\\p{Punct}"` means something else, and is [**documented**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix) as:

> Punctuation: One of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``

So, the equivalent C# is `` "[!\"#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?@\\[\\\\\\]^_`{|}~]" ``

Comment: Vote! I didn't know \\p{P} works in Java. My question is what is equivalent of \\p{Punct} in C# in POSIX  style?

Comment: @Loc C# regex does not support POSIX character classes, so use the character class Andreas shared.

Comment: @Loc C# isn't POSIX compliant so it doesn't provide POSIX character classes.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that!

Comment: @Loc I already told you what the equivalent of ``\\p{Punct}`` is in C#. Please read last line of answer.